# SQL Countdown to Date with Variable changes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write a query to give me a countdown column that counts to a different number based on another variable in the row.

So if the data in column 'a_type' is '3', I need it to count down starting at 30 days, for all other scenarios I need it to count down starting at 60 days.

I've got the countdown part working, just not the dynamic change. Any help would be awesome!

```
SELECT disturbance_date,dist_type,daysleft = DATEDIFF(DAY, getdate(), DATEADD(DAY, 60, disturbance_date)) 
FROM cwr_prime
```

Below is the result I'd like to achieve:

[image]

Comment: SQL queries return static data sets.  They don't "count".  Sample data and desired results would help explain what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Ok, I may be asking the question incorrectly, SQL is still pretty new to me. I've included a bit more info. - Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading the question correctly, I think you may be looking for a `CASE` expression inside your `DATEADD` function.

```
SELECT 
  ID, 
  a_date, 
  a_type, 
  daysleft = DATEDIFF
               (
                DAY, 
                getdate(), 
                DATEADD(DAY, CASE WHEN a_type = 3 THEN 30 ELSE 60 END, a_date)
               ) 
FROM a_table;
```